# If $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then $\gcd(2m-n-1,m-1)=2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How to prove following statement:

> If $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $\gcd(2m-n-1,m-1)=2$, where $m,n$ are odd numbers and $m>n$.

Since $m=2k_1+1$ and $n=2k_2+1$ we may write:

$2m-n-1=2(2k_1+1)-2k_2-1-1=4k_1-2k_2=2(2k_1-k_2)$

$m-1=2k_1+1-1=2k_1$

So we may conclude that common divisor is $2$ but how to prove that it is greatest common divisor of those two numbers ?

Comment: $\gcd(13,5)=1$ but $\gcd(20,12)=4\ne2$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m=9$ and $n=5$ then $\gcd(9,5) =1$ but $\gcd(2\times 9-5-1,9-1) = \gcd(12,8) =4$ so it is not true.

From your previous work, if $k_1$ and $k_2$ have a common factor but $2k_1+1$ and $2k_2+1$ do not then you will find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

<s>If $m=7$ and $n=5$, then $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $\gcd(2m-n-1,n-1)=\gcd(8,4)=4$, so</s> it would seem the proposition is not true.

**Comment added later:** Someone else gave a counterexample, with $m-1$ where I had $n-1$ above.  The comments below still stand. **End of comment added later**

Every divisor that $a$ and $b$ have in common is a divisor that $a$ and $b-a$ have in common.

Conversely, every divisor that $a$ and $b-a$ have in common is a divisor that $a$ and $b$ have in common.

Therefore the set of all common divisors of $a$ and $b$ is the same as the set of all common divisors of $a$ and $b-a$.

Therefore the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is the same as the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b-a$, and that's why Euclid's algorithm works.

Think about applying all that to similar propositions.

**Later edit:** Subtracting those $1$s at the end changes things.  I almost wonder if somehow a slightly different identity was intended---one that is correct.  But I don't know what it would be.

Comment: @JavaMan I'm not following you.  If $n=5$ then $n-1=4\ne6$.

Comment: Oh.  I see.  But someone else posted another counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

It is known/easy to prove that $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd (a \pm b,b)$.

This means that

$$\gcd(2m-n-1,m-1)=\gcd(m-n,m-1)=\gcd(m-n,m-1-(m-n))$$
$$=
\gcd(m-n,n-1)=\gcd(m-1, n-1) \,.$$

Comment: Might add here that given only that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime and odd, we can arrange for $\gcd(m-1,n-1)$ to be *any* even number.